# Detecting errors of a command that print nothing if the command was successful using Perl and Expect

Tags: regex, perl, expect

I am trying to automate the configuration of a server using perl and the expect module. I have been using the expect module three days but now I have encountered a problem that I can't solve.

My problem is when im executing a command that prints no output if it is successful but prints an error message if something went wrong. An example of such command is the `cd` command:

```
$ cd .
$ 
$ cd sadjksajdlaskd
sadjksajdlaskd: No such file or directory.
$
```

What I would like to do is to send the command to the server, and then perform an `expect` call to check if something other than the prompt sign was printed. Something like this:

```
$com->send("cd $dir");
$com->expect(2, 
        ["^[^$#]*", sub {
                 my $self = shift;
                 my $error = $self->match();
                 die "ERROR: $error";
        }],
        "-re", "^[$#]"
);
```

The problem I have is that when I perform the `expect` call it will match against all previous text and not against text received after the `send` call, so it will always match and report an error. How do I make expect match only agains the text received after the `send` call? Is it possible to clear the buffer of the expect module or is it possible to achieve this kind of error detection some other way?

I also wonder how the expect module handles regular expressions. If I for example use `"^[$#]\$"` as the regular expression to match the prompt of the terminal, will the `\$` part of the regular expression match end of line or an actual dollar sign? If i remove the `\` perl complains.

Thanks in advance!

/Haso

**EDIT: I have found a solution:**

The solution was to use `$com->clear_accum()` which clears the accumelator. I have tried using it before but it seems like this function only works at random, or maybe I don't understand what `clear_accum()` is suppose to do.

**EDIT: A final note about `clear_accum()`:**

The reason the `clear_accum()` function seems to work at random is because the text generated from the previous `send` is not read into the accumelator until an `expect()` call is made. So in order to truly clear all previous data is to first perform an `expect()` call and then clear the accumelator:

```
#To clear all previous data
$com->expect(0);
$com->clear_accum();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> akarageo@Pal4op:~> cd banana
> bash: cd: banana: No such file or directory
> akarageo@Pal4op:~:( > echo $?
> 1
> ```

i.e. check the error code that *CD*  returns, 0 means *OK* anything else is an error, No need to check the prompt , and btw, the CD command does not generate the prompt the shell does, so that must be part of your confusion also.

try  $object->exitstatus() if it is of any help

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately the server does not have bash.

Comment: It contains some kind of a shell definitely otherwise the "exec(cd)" should not work. Almost all Shells can return the last error code. In Unix systems all support $? , in windows I am no so sure, probably getLastErrorCode or such. Furthermore note that expect is written in TCL and you can do TCL primitives from it !